# How many times did Len Kagamine die?

Tags: vocaloid

How many times Len Kagamine die in all of his PV's? I have been searching the answer for this question for a long time.

Comment: Rin dies more then Len. Len only dies 15 times I believe. Ill write a full answer If I have some time tonight ;)

Comment: Uhh... is this going to be always updated based on all current and future PVs? Or is there any context I miss?

Comment: Limit this to the day the question is asked and on official PV only.

Comment: Honestly, since new vocaloid covers are made, Len probably will die an infinite number of times. But he always revives in another song. He will never die completely it seems

Answer (score -3):

I checked a million of his songs (some of which were very suicidal), and the answer for now many times Len died was 97.